# How to calculate the mean of 3D matrices in an image without NaN?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I need to calculate the mean of a 3D matrices (last step in the code). However, there are many `NaN`s in the `(diff_dataframe./dataframe_vor)` calculation. So when I use this code, some results will be `NaN`. How could I calculate the mean of this matrix by ignoring the NaNs? I attached the code as below.

```
S.amplitude = 1:20;%:20;
S.blocksize = [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10 12 15 20];
S.frameWidth = 1920;
S.frameHeight = 1080;
S.quality=0:10:100;
image = 127*ones(S.frameHeight,S.frameWidth,3);
S.yuv2rgb = [1 0 1.28033; 1 -0.21482 -0.38059; 1 2.12798 0];
i_bs = 0;
for BS = S.blocksize
i_bs = i_bs + 1;

hblocks = S.frameWidth / BS;
vblocks = S.frameHeight / BS;
i_a = 0;
dataU = randi([0 1],vblocks,hblocks);
dataV = randi([0 1],vblocks,hblocks);
dataframe_yuv = zeros(S.frameHeight, S.frameWidth, 3);
for x = 1 : hblocks
    for y = 1 : vblocks
        dataframe_yuv((y-1)*BS+1:y*BS, ...
            (x-1)*BS+1:x*BS, 2) = dataU(y,x) * 2 - 1;
        dataframe_yuv((y-1)*BS+1:y*BS, ...
            (x-1)*BS+1:x*BS, 3) = dataV(y,x) * 2 - 1;
    end
end

dataframe_rgb(:,:,1) = S.yuv2rgb(1,1) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,1) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(1,2) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,2) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(1,3) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,3);
dataframe_rgb(:,:,2) = S.yuv2rgb(2,1) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,1) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(2,2) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,2) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(2,3) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,3);
dataframe_rgb(:,:,3) = S.yuv2rgb(3,1) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,1) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(3,2) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,2) + ...
    S.yuv2rgb(3,3) * dataframe_yuv(:,:,3);
for A = S.amplitude
    i_a = i_a + 1;
    i_q = 0;
image1p = round(image + dataframe_rgb * A);
image1n = round(image - dataframe_rgb * A);
dataframe_vor = ((image1p-image1n)/2)/255;
for Q = S.quality
        i_q = i_q + 1;
namestrp = ['greyjpegs/Img_BS' num2str(BS) '_A' num2str(A) '_Q'     num2str(Q) '_1p.jpg'];
namestrn = ['greyjpegs/Img_BS' num2str(BS) '_A' num2str(A) '_Q' num2str(Q) '_1n.jpg'];
imwrite(image1p/255,namestrp,'jpg', 'Quality', Q);
imwrite(image1n/255,namestrn,'jpg', 'Quality', Q);
error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean2((abs(diff_dataframe./dataframe_vor)));
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mean2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mean2.html) is a shortcut function that's part of the image processing toolbox that finds the entire average of a 2D region which doesn't include handling `NaN`.  In that case, simply remove all values that are `NaN` and find the resulting average.  Note that the removal of `NaN` unrolls the 2D region into a 1D vector, so we can simply use `mean` in this case.  As an additional check, let's make sure there are no divide by 0 errors, so also check for `Inf` as well.

Therefore, replace this line:

```
error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean2((abs(diff_dataframe./dataframe_vor)));
```

... with:

```
tmp = abs(diff_dataframe ./ dataframe_vor);
mask = ~isnan(tmp) | ~isinf(tmp);
tmp = tmp(mask);

if isempty(tmp)
    error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = 0;
else
    error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean(tmp);
```

We first assign the desired operation to a temporary variable, use [`isnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) and [`isinf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isinf.html) to remove out the offending values, then find the average of the rest.  One intricacy is that if your **entire region** is `NaN` or `Inf`, then the removal of all these entries in the region results in the empty vector, and finding the mean of this undefined.  A separate check is there to be sure that if it's empty, simply assign the value of 0 instead.

Comment: Thank you for ur help. I tried this code, but some NaN turned to be Inf after using: `tmp = abs(diff_dataframe ./ dataframe_vor);
tmp = tmp(~isnan(tmp));
if isempty(tmp)
    error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = 0;
else
    error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean(tmp);`

Comment: That's because you may have the denominator being `0` as well. I'll change accordingly.

Comment: thank you again for ur help. sorry for the late reply. I tried this code again and now there is no NaN or Inf in the result any more. But I have a question about the result. Because we removed the `NaN` and `Inf` in the `mask` and assigned a value of `0` in the corresponding position. When we caculate the average, actually we want to only caculate average of all the non-zeros elements. for exp. (3+0+2)/3 and (3+2)/2, the results would be different, is this `error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean(tmp);` exactly aims at the average of all non-zero elements? Thank you !

Comment: @YingWang yes this handles the case of finding the mean of all nonzero elements. We assign 0 as the mean only if all elements in each window are `Inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: got it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If I have finished answering your question, I would love it if you could accept this answer to let the community know you no longer need help. That can be done by going to the top of this answer, and clicking on the checkmark icon underneath the up and down arrows buttons. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, today I tested the code again and found that `NaN` came out again. My code is showed below, there is no change in my code but why when it ran again, the result changed?                                                                             `

Comment: `diff_dataframe=dataframe_vor-dataframe_nach;                                    tmp = abs(diff_dataframe ./ dataframe_vor);          mask = ~isnan(tmp) | ~isinf(tmp);tmp = tmp(mask);                                                                                                    if isempty(tmp) error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = 0;else error_mean(i_bs, i_a, i_q) = mean(tmp);`                                                                                                                     whether the `mask = ~isnan(tmp) | ~isinf(tmp);` should be changed to `mask = ~isnan(tmp) & ~isinf(tmp);`  ?